# How to translate a table into a rdf graph?

Tags: database, properties, rdf, relational

Let's consider a table in a relational DB, with two attributes x and y, and two rows:

1) x=January, y=12
2) x=February, y=3

If I wanted to translate this in a rdf graph, I would define:

> - an URI/bnode for the table ":table1";
> - a bnode for each row "*:row1", "*:row2";

Then I should connect the rows to the table:

> _:row1 rdf:type :table1
>   _:row2 rdf:type :table1

and, finally, I should connect each row to their values in this way:

> _:row1 :x "January"
>   _:row1 :y "12"
>   _:row2 :x "February"
>   _:row2 :y "3"

Is this right so far? Other solutions?

Well, now, how to annotate x and y with some other information?
For example I need to express that x refers to the concept "Month" (which is an owl:Class btw) in a remote ontology.
My first idea is to directly use the URI "myonto:Month" instead of ":x", but my concern is that using, as a property, a remote URI (that actually is a Class of an ontology) could be somewhat conceptually wrong, or at least it could be represented better.

What do you suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

That looks like a pretty typical way to convert from tables to triples.

If you syntax is Turtle, you can write

```
_:row1 :y 12 .
```

Which is the integer 12, rather than the string "12".

You could also have a URI for the month, e.g.

```
_:row1 :x month:january
```

As you said.

Using "remote" URIs from another ontology is fine, and is recommended practice actually. It's supposed to be a Web system after all.

Comment: You should also look at http://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/ there are a number of systems that can do this mapping on the fly, though you may not get as elegant a mapping as doing it specifically for your data.

Comment: Thanks. About the last point of my post, consider that I have MyOnto with a Class named "Month" with instances "January", "February", and so forth. Now, I would like to say something like: (_:row1 myOnto:Month myOnto:January): in short I'm annotating both the table's attribute and the cell's value through a remote resource. I know that in rdf an URI is just an URI, but here I'm using a Class as a property. Besides the synctactical validity, is it semantically meaningful?